# Unable to switch from Private to Public ArcGIS Online account

Tags: arcgis-online

I just created an account using "Create Public Account" in ArcGIS Online. I add a bio/profile picture and added some public content which I made public, but then I noticed that my account type had changed to Private. When I click the drop down under Profile visibility, the only available option is Private.

How do I switch my account to Public?

I need a public account so that I can nominate content to the Living Atlas.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in similar circumstances, until I realized that the account I was trying to use was an ArcGIS public account and NOT an ArcGIS Organizational Account.

In summary, the Profile visibility of an ArcGIS public account can only be set to private, but an organizational account can be set to public.

The link below would explain it better.

https://community.esri.com/t5/learn-arcgis-blog/a-user-s-guide-to-arcgis-accounts/ba-p/886530

I hope this helps.